# Aptitude: What is the filter for virtual packages that has been provided?

Tags: aptitude

The `~v` flag will display all virtual packages, but even if they are already provided by installed packages, adding `~i` will make the list empty as virtual packages can never have `i` flag. So how do I find out what virtuals are installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want the virtual packages (`?virtual`) that are provided by (`?reverse-provides()`) an installed package (`?installed`). That's

```
?virtual ?reverse-provides(?installed)
```

or `~v ~Rprovides:~i` for short.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried so many combinations, even using to `?for` but still couldn't figure out why they don't work. Then I realized `?for` doesn't return a different package; it only applies filter with the condition given.